# How to modify cookie time for exit popup

Tags: javascript, css, cookies, popup, session-cookies

I'm trying to broaden the use of an exit popup (inside the platform Kajabi) but since I'm super new to coding (CSS & Javascript) I thought I'd see if someone has a solution.

So basically what I want to do is to modify the timing of the exit popup. I want it to be visible on the site, **every time** someone visits the page for a **total of 3 days** (or any other timeframe). Then I want the cookie to register and not show the popup for 7 days (or any other timeframe. Since I don't know if this is possible, let's just call this option 1.

Option 2 is basically trying to achieve the same thing, but having the **reverse approach**. In this setting, I don't want the popup show up for **3 days** (or any other timeframe) and after that period I want it to be visible **every time** someone visits the page.

Like I said, I don't even know if this is possible. Maybe by using some form of expire date reset on the cookie? CSS or Javascript is what I'm able to use inside of Kajabi.

Appreciate your help and feel free to guide me in any direction if you have another better alternative.

All the best,

Comment: Available options are described here: https://help.kajabi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360040195273-How-to-Use-the-Exit-Pop-Up I'd guess its rather impossible to go beyond that. Just ask the kajabi support if in doubt.

Comment: Thank you so much Hans for your comment! What if we forgot about Kajabi for a second. Are we even able to pull this off? How would you do it if you didn’t have any limitations? Thanks again!

Comment: You'd roll your own "exit popup" by using javascript to set a cookie on first visit, store the datetime of the first visit, and then show/hide the popup depending on your chosen logic. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie. To show the popup, you'd add an event listener for the "mouseout" event on document and then check if target is null, like outlined here: https://medium.com/weekly-webtips/how-to-make-an-effective-exit-intent-popup-in-javascript-bf6051b4a6d4

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to post an answer to this. I got in touch with a developer who knows Kajabi inside out, and we were able to realize the vision I had 100%. If anyone is reading this and wants to accomplish something similar inside Kajabi, just reach out and I'll guide you through it.